# Сортировка массива объектов по разным полям

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив объектов `Car[] cars`, который надо сортировать по разным полям. Например: `Id`, `Weight`, `MaxSpeed`.

Я сделал 3 метода. В них по сути повторяется одно и то же.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вместо нескольких методов, такой один метод, в который можно было бы передать параметр, по которому надо отсортировать?

```
public static void sortCarsById(Car[] cars) {
    System.out.println("\nCars were sorted by id: ");
    Car temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cars.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (cars[j].getId() > cars[j + 1].getId()) {
                temp = cars[j];
                cars[j] = cars[j + 1];
                cars[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void sortCarsByWeight(Car[] cars) {
    System.out.println("\nCars were sorted by weight: ");
    Car temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cars.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (cars[j].getWeight() > cars[j + 1].getWeight()) {
                temp = cars[j];
                cars[j] = cars[j + 1];
                cars[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void sortCarsByMaxSpeed(Car[] cars) {
    System.out.println("\nCars were sorted by max speed: ");
    Car temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cars.length - 1 - i; j++) {
            if (cars[j].getMaxSpeed() > cars[j + 1].getMaxSpeed()) {
                temp = cars[j];
                cars[j] = cars[j + 1];
                cars[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cars.sort((c1, c2) -> c1.getId().compareTo(c2.getId()));`
Или вы можете написать 3 компаратора и использовать их

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(cars, Comparator.comparing(Car::getId)); // Сортировка по id

Arrays.sort(cars, Comparator.comparing(Car::getWeight)); // Сортировка по weight

Arrays.sort(cars, Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaxSpeed)); // Сортировка по maxSpeed
```

Comment: Хотел использовать свою сортировку, но всё равно больше спасибо, воспользуюсь скорее всего вашим вариантом.
 А подскажите ещё, пожалуйста, есть ли такой же метод, но который находит сумму значений любого из полей Weight, Price и т.д.
То есть я создал два очень похожих между собой метода: первый считает сумму всех Weight, второй сумму всех Price. Но хотелось бы сделать один универсальный, чтобы только менялся параметр.